# repeatedly clicking jquery effects

Tags: jquery

I implemented jquery's fadeIn/Out for a menu like drop down on my page.

Its not hover, so it requires a click.  It works fine, no problems, EXCEPT, when you click the thing repeatedly, over and over again for no reason.

The way I have it set up is to increase the menu bars height(while fadingIn/Out the other div) on click to visually achieve a 4px border around all portions of my layout.

If you click repeatedly (lets just say youre an overactive 12 year old with ADD, or an old lady who double clicks everything), the formatting can get messed up.

Is there any solution to this?

HTML:

```
<a class="springtrail_link stadd" href="#" id="add" data-hidden="1" data-lastid="<?php echo $lastid ?>">Change Category</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.stadd').live('click', function(){
        var hidden = $(this).data('hidden')
        var lastid = $(this).data("lastid");
        var divid = "#suggested";
        if (hidden == 0)
        {
            hide(divid)
            $('.stadd').data('hidden', '1');
        } else
        {
            buildsuggested(lastid);
            show(divid);
            $('.stadd').data('hidden', '0');
        }
});  

function show(divid) {
    $(divid).slideDown('fast');
    var stheight = $('#springtrail').height();
    var pxheight = stheight + 4;
    $('#springtrail').animate({height: pxheight+'px'});
    $('#springtrail').css( 'border-bottom-left-radius' , '0px');
    $('#springtrail').css( 'border-bottom-right-radius' , '0px');
}

function hide(divid) {
    $(divid).fadeOut('fast');
    var stheight = $('#springtrail').height();
    var pxheight = stheight - 4;
    $('#springtrail').animate({height: pxheight+'px'});
    $('#springtrail').css( 'border-bottom-left-radius' , '4px');
    $('#springtrail').css( 'border-bottom-right-radius' , '4px');
}
```

Comment: Do you have some demo code for explaining your pb ?

Comment: Please post your code. My guess would be that you need to put a `stop()` in your click code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have posted no code I'm assuming your issue might be related to queued animation effects.

Let's assume some basic HTML similar to this:

```
<button type="button" id="in">In</button>
<button type="button" id="out">Out</button>
<br/>
<img id="book" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" width="100" height="123" />
```

And basic script like this:

```
$('#in').click(function() {
    $('#book').fadeIn('slow', function() {});
});

$('#out').click(function() {
    $('#book').fadeOut('slow', function() {});
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/B4CFa/) - Animation effects queued each time

The problem here is that each time you click it executes the fade effect, so clicking both buttons realy fast causes a queue. this queue will keep running after you stopped clicking to complete, which in some scenarios can lead to undesired effects.

To prevent this behaviour you can use [**jQuery's stop()**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method to stop the current animation. Similar to this:

```
$('#in').click(function() {
    $('#book').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow', function() {});
});

$('#out').click(function() {
    $('#book').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow', function() {});
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDGQQ/) - Stopping animation effects

This will now ensure to stop the animation before starting the next one, addressing some of those undesired results.

See the documentation linked above for more details on the `true, true` arguments when calling `stop()`.

Comment: Thank you, wasn't aware of stop().  I excluded code because it was essentially the same code taken off the documentation.

Comment: No worries :). In general the relevant code (or as close as possible) should be part of a question as it helps to identify if the issue possibly is something localised instead of an issue which can be fixed similar to this one. A jsFiddle, demonstrating an issue for example is a great addition to a question. Sadly not all issues are solvable with a best-guess solution. Glad you got it sorted though :)